# Is there a TypeScript equivalent to the flow-typed CLI tool?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, flowtype, flow-typed

`flow-typed` is a CLI tool that provides auto-discovery of flow type definitions for installed JS packages (and other things).

I usually use TypeScript over Flow and often find myself installing packages like this:

```sh
yarn add lodash express bluebird
yarn add --dev @types/lodash @types/express @types/bluebird
```

I recently stumbled on to `flow-typed` and its `install` command, which checks the installed packages and automatically installs the type definitions for them, as required.

With `flow-typed` I would simply do:

```sh
yarn add lodash express bluebird
flow-typed install
```

Does an equivalent tool exist for TypeScript?

Comment: it's a little old, but you might try [ts-typie](https://github.com/T-Specht/ts-typie)

Comment: There's also https://github.com/jeffijoe/typesync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the legacy version of yarn (v1) - which is still very common - I have found no solution.

However, modern yarn (v2+) supports a plugin infrastructure and just such a plugin exists: the [plugin-typescript](https://yarnpkg.com/api/modules/plugin_typescript.html).

This plugin offers a range of features, one being "Automatically adds @types/ packages into your dependencies when you add a package that doesn't include its own types".